# Getting JavaScript object key list

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object like

```
var obj = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2',
   key3: 'value3',
   key4: 'value4'
}
```

How can I get the length and list of keys in this object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Property Names In JSON Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876485/get-property-names-in-json-objects)

Comment: @TJ I think it's not totally the same. This is an object, the duplicate is a JSON object.

Comment: if you have underscore, then simply _.keys(your_object)

Comment: As things have changed since 2010, it might be better to accept the most upvoted answer as "the answer"

Answer (score 358, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3',
  key4: 'value4'
};
var keys = [];

for (var k in obj) keys.push(k);

console.log("total " + keys.length + " keys: " + keys);
```

Comment: I don't suppose Javascript is like PHP, where you can skip the first line altogether? Not that something like that is advisable to do anyway.

Comment: @Bart: No, the first line is necessary in JavaScript.

Comment: You should take a look at David Morrissey's comment below for an edge case here. Sometimes taking this approach will result in unwanted members of the prototype showing up in `keys`.

Comment: @pat: If you're using object literals, that'll only happen if you extend `Object.prototype`, which you should not be doing anyway. For custom constructors, though, you are right.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom even back in june 2010 that caused a notice, as it means you're implicitly typing the object. Assigning `[]` to it (or `array()` back then) makes it an array, which you can then use as an array safely.

Comment: @Bart there's an ugly `[]=` operator for PHP identifiers but in javascript when you do `myUndefinedVar.push` you are trying to retrieve the property `push` from and object of type `'undefined'` which causes a reference error; note I haven't even typed the parens and arguments after push

Answer (score 666):

```js
var obj = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2',
   key3: 'value3',
   key4: 'value4'
}
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
console.log('obj contains ' + keys.length + ' keys: '+  keys);
```

It's [supported](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) on most major browsers now.

Comment: The fact that it works in Chrome also means it works in Node.js as both are built on the V8 javascript engine.

Comment: @fet Nowadays, yes.  Two years ago, not so much.

Comment: Note that this is different from `for(key in ob)`! `Object.keys` wont list the keys from prototypes, but `.. in obj` does.

Comment: @fet windows7 came with IE8. As great as it would be, there's no way this can be the accepted answer until people stop using IE8.

Comment: Here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys you find a JavaScript method that works correctly in old browsers and doesn't overwrite the functionality in newer browsers.
Also see my answer below.

Comment: @Anurag What Object.keys(obj); does internally ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys has a polyfill implementation for those who want to use this and support IE 8.

Comment: WARNING: `Object.keys(obj)` would also convert all keys to strings under the hood, so if you have integers as keys, the resulting list would be wrong e.g. ['1', '2', '3'] instead of [1, 2, 3].

Answer (score 27):

Underscore.js makes the transformation pretty clean:

```
var keys = _.map(x, function(v, k) { return k; });
```

Edit: I missed that you can do this too:

```
var keys = _.keys(x);
```

Comment: That's correct, the actual underscore source:nativeKeys = Object.keys;
hasOwnProperty   = ObjProto.hasOwnProperty;
_.has = function(obj, key) {
    return hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
  };
  
  _.keys = nativeKeys || function(obj) {
    if (obj !== Object(obj)) throw new TypeError('Invalid object');
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) if (_.has(obj, key)) keys.push(key);
    return keys;
  };

Answer (score 19):

If you only want the keys which are specific to that particular object and not any derived `prototype` properties:

```
function getKeys(obj) {
    var r = []
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) 
            continue
        r.push(k)
    }
    return r
}
```

e.g:

```
var keys = getKeys({'eggs': null, 'spam': true})
var length = keys.length // access the `length` property as usual for arrays
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var keys = new Array();
for(var key in obj)
{
   keys[keys.length] = key;
}

var keyLength = keys.length;
```

to access any value from the object, you can use obj[key];

Comment: you need to increment array index

Comment: array index is incremented automatically by `keys.length`, which is different for each iteration as each iteration inserts a value.

Answer (score 4):

```
obj = {'a':'c','b':'d'}
```

You can try:

```
[index for (index in obj)]
```

this will return:

```
['a','b']
```

to get the list of keys
or

```
[obj[index] for (index in obj)]
```

to get the values

Comment: Doesn't work in Google Chrome v16.0.912.75, but it does work in Firefox v10.0

Answer (score 4):

Anurags answer is basically correct.
But to support `Object.keys(obj)` in older browsers as well you can use the code below that is copied from 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
. It adds the `Object.keys(obj)` method if it's not available from the browser.

```
if (!Object.keys) {
 Object.keys = (function() {
 'use strict';
 var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
    hasDontEnumBug = !({ toString: null }).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
    dontEnums = [
      'toString',
      'toLocaleString',
      'valueOf',
      'hasOwnProperty',
      'isPrototypeOf',
      'propertyIsEnumerable',
      'constructor'
    ],
    dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

return function(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' && (typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null)) {
    throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
  }

  var result = [], prop, i;

  for (prop in obj) {
    if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
      result.push(prop);
    }
  }

  if (hasDontEnumBug) {
    for (i = 0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
      if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) {
        result.push(dontEnums[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};
}());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Object.keys()`... it's the way to go.

Full documentation is available on the MDN site linked below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 4):

Modern browsers do support:

```js
var obj = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2',
   key3: 'value3',
   key4: 'value4'
}
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
// we can also get values
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that in coffeescript this can be accomplished in all browsers and node as

```
k for k of obj
```

and thus

```
(1 for _ of obj).length
```

Answer (score 3):

Recursive solution for browsers that support ECMAScript 5:

```
var getObjectKeys = function(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var length = keys.length;

    if (length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (typeof obj[keys[i]] === 'object') {
                keys[keys[i]] = getObjectKeys(obj[keys[i]]);
            }
        }
    }

    return keys;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2',
   key3: 'value3',
   key4: 'value4'
}

console.log(Object.keys(obj));
console.log(Object.keys(obj).length)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to use Underscore.js you better do

```js
var obj = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3',
    key4: 'value4'
}

var keys = [];
_.each( obj, function( val, key ) {
    keys.push(key);
});
console.log(keys.lenth, keys);
```

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, an object is a standalone entity, with properties and type.

For fetching values from Object in form of array: 
**Object**.values(obj) // obj is object name that you used 
*Result* -> ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]

For fetching keys from Object in form of array: 
**Object**.keys(obj) // obj is object name that you used 
*Result* -> ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4"]

As both functions are returning array you can get the length of keys or value by using length property. For instance -  **Object**.values(obj).length *or* **Object**.keys(obj).length

Answer (score 2):

For a comma-delineated string listing the keys of a JSON Object, try the following:

```
function listKeys(jObj){
    var keyString = '';
    for(var k in jObj){
        keyString+=(','+k);
    }
    return keyString.slice(1);
}



/* listKeys({'a' : 'foo', 'b' : 'foo', 'c' : 'foo'}) -> 'a,b,c' */
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6, 
you can use `forEach` to iterate over the Keys of an Object.
To get all the keys you can use `Object.keys` which returns all the keys in an Object

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(keyValue, index, map) { 
  console.log(keyValue); 
});
```

Short hand of the above snippet would be, which only takes one parameter

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(keyValue) { 
  console.log(keyValue); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       if(props.userType){
          var data = []
          Object.keys(props.userType).map(i=>{
                data.push(props.userType[i])
          })
          setService(data)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

using slice, apply and join method.

```
var print = Array.prototype.slice.apply( obj );
alert('length='+print.length+' list'+print.join());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is solution for getting all the keys from an nested object/array.**

It will recursively check for the object inside an array.

```js
function Keys() {
  let keys = [];
  this.pushKey = function (key) {
    keys.push(key);
  };
  this.getKeys = function () {
    return keys;
  };
}

let keys = new Keys();

let arr = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: {
      c: [{ d: 1, e: [{ f: 1 }] }],
    },
  },
  {
    g: 1,
    h: {
      i: [{ j: 1, k: [{ l: 1 }] }],
    },
  },
];

function getObject(arr) {
  for (let item of arr) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) getObject(item);
    else getKeys(item);
  }
}

function getKeys(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) getObject(obj[key]);
    else if (typeof obj[key] === "object") getKeys(obj[key]);
    keys.pushKey(key);
  }
}

getObject(arr);
console.log(keys.getKeys());
```