# Find values in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I have an array in my script and it's made up like this:

```
   var detail= {};
   detail['i100']=new Array()

   detail['i100']['ID 4564']= 'John'  
   detail['i100']['ID 4899']= 'Paul' 
   detail['i100']['ID 9877']= 'Andy'
   detail['i100']['ID 1233']= 'Evan'

   detail['i25'] = new Array()  

   detail['i25']['ID 89866']= 'Paul s'  
   detail['i25']['ID 87866']= 'Paul'
```

I then use this script to get the values of the first part of the array:

```
   $.each(detail, function(vehicle) {
    console.log( vehicle ) 
   });
```

This gives me two results as expected (`i100` and `i25`), What I want to do however is, by using the reference vehicle, get all the names and values of the second dimension – 
i.e. by using `i25` I want to return ID `89866` and ID `87866`. I have tried `children()`, but it is just not working. Does anyone have any advice, please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Comment: Btw, you really should not use arrays with anything else than numerical keys. `detail['i100']=new Array()` should be `detail['i100'] = {}`, i.e. it should be an object.

Comment: Maybe it's rather a duplicate of [Getting JavaScript object key list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list).

Comment: `children()` is for a jQuery set NOT for an array. Use the normal `Array` methods and accessors to get at array elements.

Comment: @FelixKling - would'nt it be converted to an object anyway with those keys (asking cause I don't know, and I'm guessing you know these things ?).

Comment: @adeneo: Well, arrays **are** objects, but they have special methods that only work on properties with numerical property names. The code is totally valid, but e.g. `detail['i25'].length` would return `0`.

Comment: @FelixKling - Yeah, but if you ran typeof, you'd get "object", right ?

Comment: @adeneo: As I said, arrays *are* objects. Always. But that `typeof arr` returns `'object'` is rather a shortcoming of the language.

Comment: @FelixKling - Okay, thanks (learns something new everyday!)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run another each on the 2nd dimension.

```
$.each(detail, function(index,value){
    $.each(value, function(i,v) {
        console.log(v);
    });
});
```

or if you want to specifically call one item, pass in the value name:

```
function getByName(name){
    $.each(detail[name], function(i,v){
        console.log(v);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '3' in i100

Comment: try it now with my edits... i forgot each callback function uses (index,value)

Comment: No prob! Glad you got it. The best way to show your appreciation is to upvote and accept my answer :)