# Iterating key-value items stored in an object

Tags: javascript, object

How to iterate over the following object so that the output listed below to be generated?

```
var obj = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" };
```

The expected output:

```
index: 0 value1: a value2: 1  
index: 1 value1: b value2: 2  
index: 2 value1: c value2: 3
```

Comment: U should refer value1 as key and value2 as value imho

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list

Comment: `obj.length` is undefined for a simple object like this ...

Comment: I'd just like to add - object keys are not ordered. The order can change across browsers or even between iterations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`for .. in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over the object's keys instead and use a separate counter for the index:

```
var index = 0;
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log("index: " + index + " value1: " + key + " value2: " + obj[key]);
    ++index;
}
```

If your environment is sane, this should just work; if not, you would have to add the mandatory [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) check.

Iterating over the object keys using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is possible in modern browsers, but if memory is tight the above method would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers you can loop like this:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, i){
  console.log('index: '+ i, 'key: '+ key, 'value: '+ obj[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an object and you are trying to iterate it as an array. Use for-in construct.

```
var obj = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" };

for(var opt in obj) {
    console.log(opt + ": " + obj[opt]);
}
```