# I parsed a JSONified array, but I can't get an specific object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JavaScript.
I used this to Jasonify an array:

```
    <script>
         var numobjects = jQuery.parseJSON('{{result|jsonify}}');
    </script>
```

and the result is correct:

```
    jQuery.parseJSON
        ('[
        {"category": "Perfumes", "comments": [good]}, 
        {"category": "Perfumes", "comments": [ok]}, 
        {"category": "Perfumes", "comments": [I like it!]}
        ]');
```

I don't now how to get the "comments" object using JavaScript.
I tried something like this:
[Getting JavaScript object key list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list)

```
    <script>
        var numobjects = [jQuery.parseJSON('{{result|jsonify}}')];
        var com = [];
          for (var comments in numobjects) com.push(comments);
            {
               console.log("total " + com.length + " comments: " + comments);
            }
   </script>
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: OK - you need to learn the developer tools. A absolute must to learn jQuery / javascript. If you query the object in the dev tools console, you will see how to drill down into the objects.

Comment: FYI, when you use `for (var <variable> in <array>)`, `<variable>` will be set to the array indexes, not the values -- it's not like PHP `foreach`

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to create another array here

`var numobjects = [jQuery.parseJSON('{{result|jsonify}}')];`

you need just parse your json:

`var numobjects = jQuery.parseJSON('{{result|jsonify}}');`

second, iterate through your array like in any other language and get your data via dot-notation:

```
var comments = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numobjects.length; i++) {
   comments.push(numobjects[i].comments);
};
alert(comments.length);
```

Comment: I've learned on SO that "I'm new to <language>" actually means "I'm new to programming", so referring them to "like in any other language" doesn't actually help them.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer was bad, just trying to give you the benefit of my experience to help you in the future.

Comment: I guess both you guys have a point, and I appreciate for the help. In this case I am new to programming considering that css and html isn't really taken as programming, although I dont have the knowledge, it is being built mostly on iterations of what I have been doing and reading. I will try to use the above and get back to you guys. tks @Tommi