# JSON file read with Select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON file (truncated):

```
{
    "** Please contact a mod by posting on the forums **": {
        "tvdb_id": "257937",
        "last_updated": 1341780286,
        "images": {
            "poster": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/posters/17288.jpg",
            "fanart": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/fanart/17288.jpg"
        }
    },
    "Jamies Best Ever Christmas": {
        "tvdb_id": "214161",
        "last_updated": 1329701153,
        "images": {
            "poster": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/posters/9126.jpg",
            "fanart": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/fanart/9126.jpg"
        }
    },
    "Kuromajo-san ga Tooru!!": {
        "tvdb_id": "257914",
        "last_updated": 1395775431,
        "images": {
            "poster": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/posters/15640.jpg",
            "fanart": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/fanart/15640.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

and this code:

```
$(".tvshow").select2({
  placeholder: "Type in a TV show",
  multiple: true,
  maximumSelectionSize: 1,
  minimumInputLength: 2,
  maximumInputLength: 20,
  query: function(query) {
    var data = {results: []};
    var value = $(".select2-input").val();
    $.ajax ({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'shows.json',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      json: "callbackname",
      crossDomain : true,
      success: function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, show) {
          // write everything in an array
          data.results.push({id: this.tvdb_id, text: this.title, poster: this.images.poster, bg: this.fanart });
          console.log(this.title);
          selectedTVshow = this.title;
          // results = data.results;

          // return array
          query.callback(data);
        })
      },
      error: function (data) {
        // console.log('error');
      }
    })
  }
})
```

When I search for `Jamies Best Ever Christmas` I want it to return the name and the respective `tvdb_id` and details.

In my above code you can see `console.log(this.title);`. This is wrong, because there is no `title:` value inside the JSON object. How can I get this to work and retrieve data?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6pGFC/ (use first input field to get autocomplete, not second)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I left an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797760/225905) on your other question that seems to line up with what you want to do. Can you help me understand why that answer won't work?

Comment: @VishalKotcherlakota: Because I’m not using Underscore.js. And it’s throwing a console error as it is: “Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain”

Comment: You need to make sure your script type is `text/javascript`, I think. Happy hunting.

Comment: BTW, jQuery has a `$.map()` feature you may find useful: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your example.

1. You dropbox file is not JSONP. It is JSON. (*so jquery cannot parse it*)
2. Since you are iterating over an object and not over an array with `$.each` the arguments passed to the function are `key` and `value`, so in your case the `i` is the key. (*see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/*)

In general the searching should happen in the server side, and not on the client (*especially for 5mb files*)

Here is demo that has fixed (*i have re-uploaded the corrected file to my dropbox*) the above two problems http://jsfiddle.net/6pGFC/3/
(*too slow though since it tries to display all the json*)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to do a mapping operation to transform the data into something easier to work with. Underscore.js is a fantastic tool for this.

```
var mappedResults = _.map(result, function(key, value, list) {
    return {name:key, tvdb_id:value.tvdb_id};
});
```

This will turn this:

```
{
    "** Please contact a mod by posting on the forums **": {
        "tvdb_id": "257937",
        "last_updated": 1341780286,
        "images": {
            "poster": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/posters/17288.jpg",
            "fanart": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/fanart/17288.jpg"
        }
    },
    "Jamies Best Ever Christmas": {
        "tvdb_id": "214161",
        "last_updated": 1329701153,
        "images": {
            "poster": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/posters/9126.jpg",
            "fanart": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/fanart/9126.jpg"
        }
    },
    "Kuromajo-san ga Tooru!!": {
        "tvdb_id": "257914",
        "last_updated": 1395775431,
        "images": {
            "poster": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/posters/15640.jpg",
            "fanart": "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/fanart/15640.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

...into this:

```
[
    {name:"** Please contact a mod by posting on the forums **", tvdb_id:"257937"},
    {name:"Jamies Best Christmas", tvdb_id:"21461"},
    {name:"Kuromajo-san ga Tooru!!", tvdb_id:"257914"}
]
```

Once that's done, you can filter it like so:

```
function getMatchingIds(searchterm) {
    return _.filter(mappedResults, function(entry) {
        return (entry.name.indexOf(searchterm) != -1);
    }
}
```

I should also add that jQuery has its own [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) feature that does something similar.