# Json created to fit a structure

Tags: javascript, json

I have created a JSON like this one :

```
{"data":[{"content":"Event1","start":"new Date(2014,07,10)"},{"content":"Event2","start":"new Date(2014,07,17)"}],"success":true}
```

In order to fit the following code in Javascript :

```
 data = [
          {
             'start': new Date(2010,7,23),
             'content': 'Event'
          },
          {
             'start': new Date(2010,7,23),
             'content': 'Event'
          },
];
```

Witth th JSON i have, i can easily access field, for example :

```
json.data[0].content
```

Return : "Event1"

My question is : how can i make the Javascript code "dynamic" to load every components in my JSON, assuming the fact that i don't know how many elements it will contains ?

Currently, i've done the followig code :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("GET", "/Test", true); // Call to a java servlet 
xhr.send();  

var json;
var jsonLength; 
var data; 

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
    json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    jsonLength = json.data.length; 
  }
}

 data = [];

 for(var i = 0 ; i < jsonLength ; i++){
    data.push({
       'start':json.data[i]['start'],
       'content':json.data[i]['content']
     })
 }

timeline.draw(data);
```

**EDIT** : I don't even enter to the for loop ... Why ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. If you have the data in a JavaScript array, why do you want or need to also keep it as a JSON string?

Comment: You can use `data.length` and use that in a `for` loop.

Comment: I do not keep it in a JSON string. The json is generated from a java servlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite simple as these are just arrays and hash objects in JavaScript.

So you can just iterate over them:

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
  var item = data[i];
  // Insert this into your data table
  // Here you can use item which is set to the current item you are iterating over
}
```

JavaScript even let's you inspect your so you can look at the individual data item and find out what properties it has like this (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list) for details):

```
var keys = [];
for(var k in obj) keys.push(k);
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems you have fallen into the asynchrosity trap that JavaScript lays out.
The function `xhr.onreadystatechange` is only called once the event happens, the code below that function is executed instantly. So you where iterating over an empty dataset since the data you where looking at was not yet loaded.

JavaScript is very much callback based and especially with AJAX. Always keep in mind when the code will run, in this case `xhr.onreadystatechange = function` returns *instantly* and the code after continues to run. Only inside the function can you expect your variables to be set correctly.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("GET", "/Test", true); // Call to a java servlet 
xhr.send();  

var json;
var jsonLength; 
var data; 

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
    json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    jsonLength = json.data.length; 


    data = [];

    for(var i = 0 ; i < jsonLength ; i++){
       data.push({
          'start':json.data[i]['start'],
          'content':json.data[i]['content']
       })
    }

    timeline.draw(data);

  }
}
```

Comment: So i will have in my loop : var item = data[i] ; data = [ {'start':'item.start', 'content':'item.content'}] ?

Comment: Almost correct - as you can see I assign the data item at the position i (the loop variable) to the variable `item` so in this case item would be { 'start': '2014-07-23 11:37', content: 'Event' } .. and on the next iteration of the loop it would contain the next values

Comment: I think i'm close ... I wrote that in a loop, but does not work : data.push({
              'start':json.data[i].start, 
              'content':json.data[i].content
             })

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't think you should push into the same array you are pulling data from.. please edit your question and explain what you are trying to do exactly so we might be able to help you in more detail

Answer (score 1):

If your json is a string, just do

```
obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then you'll have an object containing your json data, where you can access using obj[0].content (as an example)

Else, just iterate throught the json object, like Tigraine said.

(You question is a little bit unclear though)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var x={"data":[{"content":"Event1","start":"new Date(2014,07,10)"},{"content":"Event2","start":"new Date(2014,07,17)"}],"success":true};

for(i=0;i<x.data.length;i++)
    {
     console.log("content: "+x.data[i].content+" start: "+ x.data[i].start);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var json = {
            'data': [
                {
                    'start': new Date(2010, 7, 23),
                    'content': 'Event'
                },
                {
                    'start': new Date(2010, 7, 23),
                    'content': 'Event'
                },
            ]
        };
        alert(json['data'].length);
        $(function() {
        });
    </script>
```