# Javascript JSON conversion

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON like below (which is basically constructed out of a Dictionary):

`{
    "test1":["a","b","c"],
    "test2":["c","d"],
    "test3":["f"]
}`

And I want to parse and format above like this:

```
[
    {
        "user": "test1",
        "cmd": ["a","b","c"]      
    }
    {
        "user": "test2",
        "cmd": ["c","d"]
    },
    {
        "user": "test3",
        "cmd": ["f"]
    }
]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this using JavaScript?

Comment: **[What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)**?

Comment: If you obtain a list of keys for this dictionary, then the solution will be straightforward: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list

Comment: [**There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"**](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)!

Comment: @JosephSilber - [The JSON Object on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) (JSON is actually an Object in JS) ps: I know what you meant.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Have you read that article I linked to? [Did you see this](http://i.imgur.com/u40ZA8H.png)?

Comment: @JosephSilber - [But did you see this though?](http://imgur.com/wWi78pS)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Yes, but you were just repeating what the article I linked to already says.

Comment: @JosephSilber Oh wow I totally missed that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question if your dictionary is a JS object or a JSON string. If it's JSON, you'll have to first parse it:

```
var dictionary = JSON.parse(theJSONstring);
```

then follow the instructions below.

If you're supporting IE8-, you'll have to [polyfill JSON support](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

---

```
var dictionary = {
    "test1": ["a","b","c"],
    "test2": ["c","d"],
    "test3": ["f"],
};

var commands = Object.keys(dictionary).map(function (key) {
    return { user: key, cmd: dictionary[key] };
});
```

---

If you're unfortunate enough that you have to support ancient browsers (IE8-), use this:

```
var dictionary = {
    "test1":["a","b","c"],
    "test2":["c","d"],
    "test3":["f"],
};

var commands = [];

for (var key in dictionary) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dictionary, key))
    {
        commands.push({ user: key, cmd: dictionary[key] });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key))`?

Comment: @nnnnnn - Crockford reccomends it, in case someone was stupid enough to add their own `hasOwnProperty` somewhere in the prototype chain.

Comment: @nnnnnn - [Because `hasOwnProperty` could be overwrote by something else.](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter8.html#p2420ca9a47b21ef8)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var testObject = {
    "test1": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "test2": ["c", "d"],
        "test3": ["f"]
},
userArray = [];

for (test in testObject) {

    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(testObject, test)) {

        userArray.push({
            user: test,
            cmd: testObject[test]
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Ok... what about my code? Works perfectly fine.... [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq3a0htu/)

Comment: @JosephSilber I'm confused: why do we need to use `hasOwnProperty` here?

Comment: You did not fix your answer. You broke it.