# jQuery map object to keep all in second array

Tags: jquery

I have a json object (much larger):

```
data: {
pistonNoiseColdIdle: 6.5,
pistonNoiseColdSnap: 6.5,
pistonNoiseColdSweep: 6.5,
pistonNoiseHotIdle: 6.5,
pistonNoiseHotSnap: 6.5
}
```

And I want to keep only what's in a second array:

```
["pistonNoiseColdIdle", "pistonNoiseColdSnap", "pistonNoiseColdSweep", "pistonNoiseHotIdle", "pistonNoiseHotSnap"]
```

How do I output an object by filtering through the large one?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, updated

```
var arr = ["pistonNoiseColdIdle"
          , "pistonNoiseColdSnap"
          , "pistonNoiseColdSweep"
          , "pistonNoiseHotIdle"
          , "pistonNoiseHotSnap"];

var data = {
pistonNoiseColdIdle: 6.5,
pistonNoiseColdSnap: 6.5,
pistonNoiseColdSweep: 6.5,
pistonNoiseHotIdle: 6.5,
pistonNoiseHotSnap: 6.5,
other : 0
};

var _data = {};

$.map(arr, function(v, k) {
    return data[v] != undefined ? _data[v] = data[v] : null
}); 

console.log(_data);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/shfe43fs/

Comment: Please see above comments. I need to match the array to the object and keep the matching key/value pair in the data object.

Comment: If interpret accurately , map the `data` object to an `array` ? Or , find properties within the `data` object which match the "And I want to keep only what's in a second array" ? If possible , please clarify ? Thanks

Comment: I have an object and an array. I want to keep the key/value pair of the object based on the values in the array. So, if the object has 30 key/values and the array has the ones mentioned above, I want the resulting object to only contain the key/value corresponding to the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` method ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys )

```
var obj = { data: {
pistonNoiseColdIdle: 6.5,
pistonNoiseColdSnap: 6.5,
pistonNoiseColdSweep: 6.5,
pistonNoiseHotIdle: 6.5,
pistonNoiseHotSnap: 6.5
} };

var myArray = Object.keys(obj.data);
```

---

**edited after comment:**

If you want to create a new object with the keys specified in your array, maybe you can try iterating the array?

```
var obj = { data: {
pistonNoiseColdIdle: 6.5,
pistonNoiseColdSnap: 6.5,
pistonNoiseColdSweep: 4.5,
pistonNoiseHotIdle: 6.5,
pistonNoiseHotSnap: 1.5
} };

var myArray = ["pistonNoiseColdIdle", "pistonNoiseColdSnap", "pistonNoiseColdSweep", "pistonNoiseHotIdle", "pistonNoiseHotSnap"];

var filteredObj = {};
for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
    key = myArray[i];
    filteredObj[key] = obj.data[key];
}

// var filteredObj will contain only the keys in "myArray"
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question didn't make sense. I want to match the keys in the obj to the array provided and keep the matching key/value pair in a new object.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my explanation was poor. Guest guy got it below.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to just loop over the second array and add relevant properties to a new object:

```
var obj = {data: {
    pistonNoiseColdIdle: 6.5,
    pistonNoiseColdSnap: 6.5,
    pistonNoiseColdSweep: 6.5,
    pistonNoiseHotIdle: 6.5,
    pistonNoiseHotSnap: 6.5
}};
var props = ["pistonNoiseColdIdle", "pistonNoiseColdSnap", "pistonNoiseColdSweep", "pistonNoiseHotIdle", "pistonNoiseHotSnap"];

var result = new Object();
$.each(props, function(item) {
    if(obj.data.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        result[item] = obj.data[item];
    }
});

//now result object contains what you need
```

Comment: The result object is empty? I'm looking for result to be `obj` with the only remaining keys to be what's in the props. ie, if props contains only three attributes, the result object should have the matching key/value pair.