# Processing ajax result dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

So here's the thing. I have 3 inputboxes that function as table cells(the header). I also run a script that, if one of the inputboxes' input has changed, fires a function that fetches data from my database, using an ajax request. A json is returned. Now I fetch objects from the data(json) returned, so I get something like {key1: '1', key2: 'myName', ...}. Now, the "problem" is that I don't know what the keynames are(I know the keynames but I don't want to use them). Yet I want all of the keys' values listed in separate arrays.

The script I have right now:

```
$.ajax({ //ajax request
    method: "POST",
    url: "../php/fetch.php",
    data: inputs,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        var j=0;
        var otp;
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var obj = data[i];
            console.log(obj.length);
            for(p=0; p<obj.length; p++){
                otp = obj[0];
                console.log(otp);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

So I have written the code above but I get stuck at assigning the values. How do I get all keyvalues into separate arrays without knowing the column_names?

---

**EDIT:** I don't want to get the key values but I want to get the keyvalues their own array that contains the values from the database (of this particular key).

---

***Example:***

A json is returned `[{key1: "value1", key2: "value2", /*more values*/...}, {key1: "value10", key2: "value20", /*more values*/...}]` something like that. I create an `obj` that contains "a part of the json", like this `{key1: "value1", key2: "value2", /*more values*/...}`.

***What I want:***

I want to create an array from the `obj` that contains `["value 1", "value10"]` in this case for `key1`. So for every `key1` value in the json, get it and put it in an array. 
I already tried `obj.keys[0]` but that returns 0 as a value (which doesn't match any value in my json at all)

---

Thank you very much for your help in advance! :)

Evoc

Ps. if anything is unclear feel free to ask, of course.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Yet I want all of the keys' values listed in separate arrays." Can you provide an example of what is the expected outcome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list

Comment: use `Object.keys()` to return array of key names

Comment: I have multiple keys (f.e. id, name, surname, etc.) and I want all of their values into a different array. So id would have 1 and 2 for example and I can just extract the values from that array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have something like this:

```
var tmpObject = {}

data.forEach(function (row) {
  Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
    if (tmpObject[key]) {
      tmpObject[key].push(row[key]);
    } else {
      tmpObject[key] = new Array(row[key]);
    }
  });
});
```

For a `data` object like this:

```
[{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}, {key1: "value10", key2: "value20"}]
```

Should create another objet like this:

```
{
  key1: ["value1", "value10"],
  key2: ["value2", "value20"]
}
```

Comment: but I don't want the keys in the same array. I want the keys to have their own array with their own values if you understand what I mean

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean. Can you write an example of the result that you expect?

Comment: Please have a look at the question

Comment: @Evochrome, now I think I get it. I edited the answer.

Comment: what is @Eloy is trying to show is that data structures in JS are a bit different so there are classic means to convert em to what u need