# Javascript Sort a hash by values in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have a hash like below

```
 a ={ 
     0: [0, "A9"],
     2: [0, "A9.4"],           
     8: [0, "A9.1"],
     6: [1, "A9.5"],
     5: [0, "A9.2"],
     7: [2, "A9.3"]
 };
```

I need a sorted array corresponding to the second element of the array of every Value.

***i.e*** if my array is in the form of `a = {key: [value_1_integer, value_2_string]}`

I need to sort my hash by `value_2_string` so result array is

```
result = [0, 8, 5, 7, 2, 6]
```

Comment: You need to post your code and explain what went wrong with it.  Stack Overflow is not a "write my code" service, but we will help if you try and run into problems :)

Comment: I agree with @Archer. Also, better replace 'hash' with 'hashmap' or similar - a 'hash' usually refers to the value resulting from hashing an object, not the datastructure.

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting JavaScript object key list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3068534/218196) and [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/218196). Try to divide the problem into sub-problems and find solutions for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on the keys with a callback which takes the second elements of the property for sorting.

```js
var object = { 0: [0, "A9"], 2: [0, "A9.4"], 8: [0, "A9.1"], 6: [1, "A9.5"], 5: [0, "A9.2"], 7: [2, "A9.3"] },
    keys = Object.keys(object).sort(function (a, b) {
        return object[a][1].localeCompare(object[b][1]);
    });

console.log(keys);
```