# Getting JavaScript object key list vol. 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here is original question: [Getting JavaScript object key list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list)

But if the situation is little bit more complex like:

```
var obj = [
   { key1: 'value1' },
   { key2: 'value2' },
   { key3: 'value3' },
   { key4: 'value4' }
]
```

Then how you get keys like that?

```
[key1,key2,key3,key4]
```

Comment: In your code snippet, `obj` is not a plain object, but rather an array.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use mix of `Object.keys` and `Array#flatMap`.

```js
let obj = [
   { key1: 'value1' },
   { key2: 'value2' },
   { key3: 'value3' },
   { key4: 'value4' },
];

let keys = obj.flatMap(Object.keys);

console.log(keys);
```

Comment: thanks for this.. can be made shorter to `[].concat(...obj.map(Object.keys));`.

Answer (score 7):

you can get keys for each object in obj and then use `concat()` to add it to your result array.

```js
    var obj = [
       {
           key1: 'value1'
       },
       {
           key2: 'value2'
       },
       {   
           key3: 'value3'
       },
       {   
           key4: 'value4'
       }
    ]
var keyList = [];
obj.forEach(function(o){
    keyList = keyList.concat(Object.keys(o));
});
console.log(keyList);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var obj = [{
  key1: 'value1'
}, {
  key2: 'value2'
}, {
  key3: 'value3'
}, {
  key4: 'value4'
}];

var res = obj
  // iterate over the array
  .reduce(function(arr, o) {
    // get keys and push into the array
    [].push.apply(arr, Object.keys(o));
    // return the araray reference
    return arr;
    // set initial value as an empty array
  }, []);

console.log(res);

// ES6 alternative
var res1 = obj.reduce((arr, o) => (arr.push(...Object.keys(o)), arr), []);

console.log(res1);
```

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {",`

Comment: It looks strange to me to see `arr.push` mutating the array inside a `reduce`. Why not return `[...arr, Object.keys(o)]`, or do the same with `concat`?

Comment: @TomFenech : which generates new array all the time.... in that way `map()` method is better than `reduce()` ,.... That may be better I'm not sure about it :)

Comment: Yes, creating new objects incurs a (very slight) performance penalty, but if you're just gonna push to an array, you may as well use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`Array#reduce()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNxdLJtojVAhWDsI8KHR15BTwQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Freduce&usg=AFQjCNHHMuqxJ882tP03jasOvA3-26VV9Q) and [`Object.keys()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjhqOP7tojVAhVFs48KHZeeDXMQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&usg=AFQjCNHxNfTCTiOC4tCXBdJjQ2o4l76MOw) .Reduce create the array with in function and `forEach` iterate the inner Object keys

```js
var obj = [ { key1: 'value1' }, { key2: 'value2' }, { 
key3: 'value3' }, { 
key4: 'value4' } ]


console.log(obj.reduce(function(a,b){
 Object.keys(b).forEach(function(val){
   a.push(val)
  })
  return a;
},[]))
```

Comment: somebody follow me to down vote all my `array`  question .why?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over object properties with **for in**, something like this.

```js
var obj = [
   { key1: 'value1' },
   { key2: 'value2' },
   { key3: 'value3' },
   { key4: 'value4' }
],
keysArray = [];

obj.forEach((item)=>{
    for(key in item){
      keysArray.push(key);
    }
});
    
console.log(keysArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Arrows, looks bit odd because of `[0]` :/

```js
var obj = [
   { key1: 'value1' },
   { key2: 'value2' },
   { key3: 'value3' },
   { key4: 'value4' }
];

var result = obj.map(x => Object.keys(x)[0]);

console.log(result);
```

And if there are more than one key value pair, then

```
obj.map(Object.keys).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));
```

Other ways:

```
[].concat(...obj.map(Object.keys));

[].concat.apply(this, obj.map(Object.keys));
```

Or using Lodash (*which I use a lot*)

```
_.flatten(obj.map(Object.keys))
```