# Get all JSON keys in order of which they are defined

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON

```
    var x = {
    "dialog_trunk_1":{
        "message": "This is just a JSON Test"
    },

    "dialog_trunk_2":{
        "message": "and a test of the second message"
    },

    "dialog_trunk_3":
    {
        "message": "This is a test of a bit longer text. Hopefully this will at the very least create 3 lines and trigger us to go on to another box. So we can test multi-box functionality, too."
    }
}
```

Where I need to get all the keys in the order which they are defined. I have seen the Object.Entries ECMA6. Not sure how to use.

I have tried with simple for

```
keys = []
for(var key in x)
{
keys.push(key)
}
```

But this order is unexpected.

The expected results must be

```
keys = ["dialog_trunk_1","dialog_trunk_2","dialog_trunk_3"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting JavaScript object key list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list)

Comment: [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: In javascript, object properties are not guaranteed a specific order, so if you want to maintain order, you can write the object properties into an array of objects. And then you can loop over that array.

Comment: "*The expected results must be...*" - why? This feels like you're addressing the wrong problem (see "[what is the xy problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)"); as such if you can tell us the problem you're trying to solve by guaranteeing the order of keys we might be able to offer a more useful solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

Comment: Does it guarantee order?

Comment: `for ... in` has the same order since ES2020, so this makes no difference.